# Low variables and wyvern

Tags: low-variables

I have created a low variable that uses wyvern for a section of the page, although i cannot get the wyvern content to display at all.

[image: Screen Shot of low variable]

My code to call in the variable is :

{exp:low_variables:pair var="gv-online-training"}
    {gv-online-training}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}

What am i doing wrong anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the tag pair is what you are looking for. Try the single tag:

```
{exp:low_variables:single var="gv-online-training"}
```

Or alternatively, just:

```
{gv-online-training}
```